# QGIS 1.8 will not start on Windows 7

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded QGIS 1.8 and installed it on my windows 7 system. When I click on the desktop icon, nothing happens.

I am currently running QGIS 1.7.4 with no problems and the installs of previous versions have always worked with no problems. I'm not sure what's going on here. Has anyone else experienced this and have a solution?

Comment: workslike a charm for me on win 7. Did you previously uninstall version 1.74 before installing 1.8?.Are you using the standalone-installer?. Suggestion: If both versions are installed try uninstalling both. delete c:\user\.qis manually and do a fresh install with the standalone installer for version 1.8

Comment: correction: delete c:\user\username\.qgis maybe it is also named c:\users\username\.gis (I have a german win 7, where it is called benutzer)

Comment: There is something else going on here.  I have 1.8 installed on my laptop at work, and it starts fine.  I have it installed on my workstation at home, and it will not start up.  Both are Windows 7 machines.  Both were installed using the OSGeo4W installer.  At home on startup, the .bat file runs and splash screen comes up, then disappears and no further process runs.  @underdark, any ideas to test?

Comment: Did you have any other (non OSGeo4W) version installed at any point? Then a clean uninstall should help. Also make sure once more the C++ Redistributable is installed. If nothing has changed on your system since 1.7.4 worked, that shouldn't be the cause but it's usually the problem if QGIS doesn't launch.

Comment: Was the QGS 1.7.4 also installed with OSGeo4W installer? The installer can be the problem. It copies a load of zipped stuff in the ..\user\downloads\ folder, maybe the .bat files responsible for opening bz2 packages and copying the files couldnt handle it. Try using the standalone installer.

Answer (score 1):

Try install the Microsoft C++ 2005. The QGIS need this aplication to run

http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-C-2005-Redistributable-Package-x86/3000-2070_4-10726885.html

Comment: If 1.7.4 works, the C++ package cannot be missing.

Comment: Hello underdark
I have the 1.7.4 installed and when I upgrade to the 1.8 I've noticed that the OSGeo4W installer have installed the C++ package (!?). That's why I refered if the package are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the file paths in your qgis.bat. Could you post the contents of your qgis.bat? For example, if it looks like the following

```
 @echo off

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\lib
start "Quantum GIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.exe %*\
```

You might want change the path in

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa
```

to its short name version

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Progra~1\Quantu~2
```

or whatever its short name is. Save and then try loading QGIS again. It seems to be having problems with paths that have spaces. I hope that helps.

Comment: If Qgis 1.7.4 is already installed, it should most probably be Quantu~2. Otherwise the old version will be started.

Comment: Fixed it to reflect that the path names changed. Thanks for pointing it out.