# Launching QGis 1.8.0 Lisboa on Windows 8 getting an error "the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library"

Tags: qgis, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix QGIS error “Entry Point could not be located”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

I have a problem with QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa installed on a desktop with Windows 8 Pro.
When I launch qgis.bat the message "The procedure entry point ?minimum@QAbstractSlider@@QBEHXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Progra~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\phonon4.dll" appears.

I would like to precise that when I installed QGIS 1.8 for the first time it ran correctly.

I think that some Windows update or new software installations caused the problem.

If I try to re-install QGIS nothing changes.

Is there a possibility to restore the situation?

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to install QGIS in a folder without blanks. The OSGeo4W installer does this by default, the standalone does not. The default `C:\Programs (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\` spoils some parts of the installation.

And please use a fresh version of OSGeo4w setup.exe, because older versions were also broken.

Comment: I tried with your suggestions, but the result is the same

Comment: Ok, but the path in the error message should be different. Is the dll there? Try copying it to \apps\qgis\bin. Furthermore, search your hard disk for dlls of that name. Maybe another version is interfering. The right one should be from Feb 2011.

Comment: Solved! I copied all files in \OSGeo4W\bin\ to \OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin\. At first time I moved only phonon4.dll: then, launching qgis.bat a new error appeared (qwt5.dll missing). I found another post regarding this problem (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31038/how-can-i-fix-qgis-1-8-startup-issues-due-to-missing-qwt5-dll-library) and I fixed the problem. Now QGIS seems working fine! Thanks